# url access in ssrs is always redirected

Tags: reporting-services

I have installed SSRS 2012 on my server. With the web interface at
`https://myServer/Reports` I can access and manage it. I added a folder "TestTemplates" with
a report template "IssuerSectors". When clicking on the template, a valid report is generated.

When I try to access the same report via Url access (as described in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx),
my page is always redirected to `https://myServer/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx`

I have tried many combinations, as e.g.

`http://myServer/Reports?%2fTestTemplates%2fIssuerSectors&rs:Command=Render
https://myServer/Reports?%2fTestTemplates%2fIssuerSectors&rs:Command=Render
http://myServer/Reports?/TestTemplates/IssuerSectors&rs:Command=Render`

and so on. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access your report like that, you need to go to a different URL:

```
http://myServer/ReportServer
```

and then append the report folder, name, parameters, etc.

For URL access it is `ReportServer`, not `Reports` (please also note that these names can be configured in the SSRS configuration tool, so they could be different from the default names I've assumed here).

If you enter that URL in your browser, you can browse the directory structure of the report server. Navigate to your report and you'll see the URL you need to use in your browser's URL bar.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for fast answer.

Comment: Is there any other config i should be aware of to enable this feature? I've tried everything and it just dumps me to the homepage in my browser.